# Reading Perl script command output using paramiko from remote ssh

Tags: python, linux, perl, ssh, paramiko

I can't read a perl script command out from shh. I can reading things like ifconfig, pwd but I installed an application written in perl but cant read out from its command from another server when using remote ssh. Tried a lot of steps

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname=sys_ip,
            port=22,
            username=sys_username,
            password=sys_password)

cmd = "cd /; export TERM=${TERM:-dumb}; commandforperlscript"
```

I get no output and no errors.

Comment: Have you tried running the command from bash with verbosity set?
$ ssh -vvv user@host  cmd

Comment: Have you tried running the command directly on the remote machine?  Do you have correct permissions to run it?  Are you invoking it correctly?  Perhaps no output is 'expected' with that particular invokation.  Perhaps the Term:-dumb part is the problem, try removing that.

Comment: When i remove the Term:-dumb part i get the error TERM environment variable not set. I tried running directly on the remote machine and its give an output.

Comment: Have you tried other TERM settings?  TERM=xterm perhaps?
You can use it directly as in 'TERM=foo commandforperlscript'
man 7 term gives more info.

Comment: tried foo and xterm, still no output. but other commands like help --grep, ifconfig works but not the perl script command

Comment: If you redirect the output of the script to a file, does it get written?
Just add '> perloutput' to the end of your command.  If it gets written, you could just scp it over and read that.

Comment: it doesn't write. The file is empty

Comment: Try creating a simple perl script that just outputs hello world.  Now try calling that script instead of you perl script.  Does it still not output anything?  You may need to redirect the output to /tmp/foo if you do not have write permissions on /

Comment: solved the problem with "expect" and 'spawn'  . had to force it to interactive mode